# Angular 2. Получение значения input в классе компонента

Tags: javascript, angular2

Имеется `search.component.html`, и `search.component.ts`.

В `html` документе разметка поля поиска с `input` полями, при вводе в эти поля необходимо передать все значения в `search.component.ts`. Вопрос как это реализовать не загромождая `search.component.html` логикой.

```
    @Component({
       ...
    })

    export class SearchComponent {
       myMethod() {
          // тут получить значения всех инпутов, 
          // могу ли я хранить ссылки на них и тут тянуть value
       }
    }
```

Знаний в этой области у меня очень мало, если что не дописал или написал, прошу указать в комментариях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgModel-directive.html):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <input [(ngModel)] = "value1">
      <input [(ngModel)] = "value2">

      <button (click)="search()">Search</button>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  value1: string;
  value2: string;
  constructor() {

  }
  search(){
    alert(`value1: ${this.value1} \n value2: ${this.value2}`);
  }
}
```

Работающий пример: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EASr4ZOJ4APijoYTgyRt?p=preview)